# Getting 2 Top 5 within a single LINQ query in EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.1

I want to load 10 latest products containing 5 of category A and 5 of category B.
So the result contains 5 latest products with category A and 5 latest products of category B.

Normally I can do it using these two:

```cs
var listA = await (
    from p in db.Set<Product>()
    where p.Category == "A"
    orderby p.ProductDate descending
    select p
).Take(5).ToListAsync();

var listB = await (
    from p in db.Set<Product>()
    where p.Category == "B"
    orderby p.ProductDate descending
    select p
).Take(5).ToListAsync();

var result = listA.Concat(listB);
```

But as you see this piece of code requires 2 calls to the database.

How can I get the result, using just 1 database call?

Comment: Try following : var results = (from p in db.Set<Product>()
                         where (p.Category == "A") || (p.Category == "B")
                         orderby p.ProductDate descending
                         select p)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Take(5))
                    .ToList();

Comment: You are getting them all, not just the top 5??

Comment: @ErikEJ Oops, you're right, just corrected the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) before `await`

```
var listA = (
    from p in db.Set<Product>()
    where p.Category == "A"
    orderby p.ProductDate descending
    select p
).Take(5);

var listB = (
    from p in db.Set<Product>()
    where p.Category == "B"
    orderby p.ProductDate descending
    select p
).Take(5);

var result= await listA.Concat(listB).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. They asked how to get the wanted result with a single LINQ query. -- edit: well, I guess this is technically a single query, but I think OP wants to reduce the lines of code.

Comment: Really? Is it using just one database request?

Comment: @FurkanKambay No, I'm not looking for fewer lines of code. I want to reduce the database requests to improve the performance.

Comment: @mehrandvd - yes this will be sent as one database request :)

Comment: @Aducci *"yes this will be sent as one database request* Actually no, it won't. It would be nice if you check the things you are talking about. The truth is that at this time none of the released EF Core version translates `Concat` / `Union`, so what you are suggesting currently is equivalent of OP code. May be some day in the future (3.0+) it would work the way you think id does, but for sure that day is not today.

Comment: @mehrandvd Unfortunately currently there is no way (other than raw SQL of course) to get the behavior you want. Still it's recommended to use the approach from this answer - at least some day in the future it has a chance to work the desired way.

Comment: @IvanStoev In an answer, Ehsan shared a link saying the EF team confirmed the support for "set operations" on preview 7.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-7-and-entity-framework-6-3-preview-7/

Comment: @mehrandvd That's exactly what I was talking about. Good news, but you have to wait a few more months for 3.0 release - I don't recommend using any "preview" version - even in the latest preview 7 many even simple things do not work (are broken).

Answer (score 3):

With EF Core 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6, you can write it like this which produces just a single query and works perfectly fine :

```
IQueryable<Product> topA = context.Products
    .Where(p => p.Category == "A")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductDate)
    .Take(5);

IQueryable<Product> topB = context.Products
    .Where(p => p.Category == "B")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductDate)
    .Take(5);

List<Product> result = await topA
    .Concat(topB)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Category)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, The EF team has [confirmed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-7-and-entity-framework-6-3-preview-7/) that translation of UNION, CONCAT, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT is going to be added to EF Core 3. 
So, If you are using EF Core 3 Preview then good luck otherwise you have to use RAW SQL queries if you want to go with one shot.

Comment: Good news! But at the same time the link contains *"You can still expect some **common query functionality** to be **missing or broken** in this preview."*, so whether using a 3.0 preview is good luck or not is … let say, debatable :) If you ask me, they shouldn't have released any "preview" versions, but of course, free beta testers are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ Query something like this should work:

```
 var list = await(db.Product.Where(p => p.Category == "A" || p.Category == "B").OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductDate)
                                .ToList()
                                .GroupBy(p => p.Category)
                                .SelectMany(t => t.Select(b => b).Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, 5), (j, i) => j))).ToListAsync();
```